# Is max-instance flag available in selenium grid 4?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I've got selenium version 4.18.1 and the same selenium server
I have this json file and this cli command `java -jar selenium-server-4.18.1.jar node --selenium-manager true --config config_chrome.json`

```
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "maxInstances": 3,
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        }
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 5,
    "port": 5555,
    "host": "http://192.168.0.102:4444/wd/hub",
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444,
    "hubHost": "http://192.168.0.102:4444/wd/hub"
  }
}
```

But it does not affect in any way grid, I am still able to run 4-8 instances of chrome.
After reading through documentation, I created this toml file

```
[node]
driver = ["chrome"]
maxInstances = 3
```

But it's still not picking it.
Is it possible to pass the maxInstance command to the selenium grid 4.18.1?
How can I set maxInstance for chrome browser to 3?